# Pulling Multiple Items from SharePoint List to place in an Email

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, reports, flow

Is there a way to pull multiple items with a SPD workflow or Flow, and send them via email to a recipient.

Currently, we are sending them for every new item that is created, but they would rather have it report style where they get multiple responses at once.

We are using SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SharePoint Designer Workflow and Call the SharePoint Rest API. Instead of retrieving a single item, you would get a collection of items from your rest call. Here's an example of something similar:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Answer (score 0):

What is your time period? You can set an alert after a changed item (I don't know frequency) with a pause of length of time. You can then use "Get Items" in Flow to pull things based on the created time. You'll have to write an OData filter.

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part1-protocol.html

Pass them to an HTMl array or CSV file and you can send that in an email.